# [Linux][Bluez][Bluetooth] Failed to re-connect after forgetting while using NoInputNoOutput with bluetooth agent

Tags: linux-kernel, bluetooth, bluez, bluetooth-gatt

System is running below:

- Bluez_version: 5.65
- Linux Kernel version: 5.15.77-3

In this case let's call the system that's having the issue is called DUT

Steps to reproduce(Scenario):

- Set the bluetooth agent capability NoInputNoOutput for the
  default-agent on the DUT using bluetoothctl
- Take a phone turn on bluetooth and search for the DUT Now wait for the DUT to show up in the phone BT menu, click on the DUT so that pairing is initiated Now
- the phone is connected to the DUT without issues and no passcode is displayed as NoInputNoOutput is selected on the DUT in step 1
- Now forget the DUT from the phone Now turn of BT on the phone, turn it back on
- Now wait for the DUT to show up in the phone BT menu Now try
  to pair again
- The connection fails --> Issue is observed

The hcidump when the connection fails is as below:

```
> ACL data: handle 11 flags 0x02 dlen 12
    L2CAP(s): Disconn req: dcid 0x0040 scid 0x0408
< ACL data: handle 11 flags 0x00 dlen 12
    L2CAP(s): Disconn rsp: dcid 0x0040 scid 0x0408
> HCI Event: Link Supervision Timeout Change (0x38) plen 4
    handle 11 timeout 32000
> HCI Event: IO Capability Response (0x32) plen 9
    bdaddr 14:F2:87:BA:90:94 capability 0x01 oob 0x00 auth 0x04
    Capability: DisplayYesNo (OOB data not present)
    Authentication: General Bonding (No MITM Protection)
> HCI Event: IO Capability Request (0x31) plen 6
    bdaddr 14:F2:87:BA:90:94
< HCI Command: IO Capability Request Reply (0x01|0x002b) plen 9
    bdaddr 14:F2:87:BA:90:94 capability 0x03 oob 0x00 auth 0x04
    Capability: NoInputNoOutput (OOB data not present)
    Authentication: General Bonding (No MITM Protection)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 10
    IO Capability Request Reply (0x01|0x002b) ncmd 1
    status 0x00 bdaddr 14:F2:87:BA:90:94
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5
    handle 11 packets 1
> HCI Event: User Confirmation Request (0x33) plen 10
    bdaddr 14:F2:87:BA:90:94 passkey 713305
< HCI Command: User Confirmation Request Negative Reply (0x01|0x002d) plen 6
    bdaddr 14:F2:87:BA:90:94
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 10
    User Confirmation Request Negative Reply (0x01|0x002d) ncmd 1
    status 0x00 bdaddr 14:F2:87:BA:90:94
> HCI Event: Simple Pairing Complete (0x36) plen 7
    status 0x05 bdaddr 14:F2:87:BA:90:94
    Error: Authentication Failure
```

Note: I tried the above scenario both with an iphone and an android phone same issue is observed

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `JustWorksRepairing = always` in the `etc/bluetooth/main.conf`, this looks like a regression in the latest kernel after 4.19 and we need the JustWorksRepairing to make this to work.

FYI, More discussion can be found here:

Related Patch discussions:

'[PATCH 0/1] Bluetooth: Fix Just-Works re-pairing' - MARC
'[PATCH 1/1] Bluetooth: Fix Just-Works re-pairing' - MARC